# GitHub App authentication problem: could not refresh installation id token

Tags: go, github, github-api

I'm having a problem authenticating with a GitHub App correctly against Github.

I'm using this example:

https://github.com/swinton/example-golang-github-app/blob/main/go-probot/probot.go

I simply change the following code:

https://github.com/swinton/example-golang-github-app/blob/99e6061c5da3ec7b191d389b45e262acf4d4632f/go-probot/app.go#L58

To use the next one (it doesn't work for me with any); since I don't use my own installation:

`client := github.NewClient(&http.Client{Transport: itr})`

The error it shows is:

`could not refresh installation id 140xxxx28's token: request received non 2xx response status`

I'm using ghinstallation as google/go-github library recommends.

I think I have everything set up correctly. If I don't interact with the API, I receive the webhooks correctly. It is when I make a call against the API that I receive the previous message.

```
set GITHUB_BASE_URL=https://api.github.com/
set GITHUB_APP_ID=9xxx4
set GITHUB_APP_PRIVATE_KEY_PATH=x-01-11.private-key.pem
set GITHUB_APP_WEBHOOK_SECRET=gaxxxxias
```

[image]

Some idea?

Thank you so much

---

Edit: complete error trace

```
time="2021-01-11T20:59:41+01:00" level=info msg="Post \"https://api.github.com/repos/xxxxxxx/example-app/pulls/552756737/comments\": could not refresh installation id 140xx928's token: request &{Method:POST URL:https://api.github.com/app/installations/140xx928/access_tokens Proto:HTTP/1.1 ProtoM
ajor:1 ProtoMinor:1 Header:map[Accept:[application/vnd.github.machine-man-preview+json application/vnd.github.machine-man-preview+json] Authorization:[Bearer eyJhbGciOiJSUzIxxxxxXXXXxxxxxxxS5doAR1fAd-h2qh6IXhiIjmdgBKZhJRWgRu2TBZOrpVPuCxTRxEGoQUqRKRVDyfSWgHqEVCo3GWvZUG0ClWqGHr6adl2Ca0g] Content-Type:[appl
ication/json]] Body:{Reader:} GetBody:0x6bcbe0 ContentLength:5 TransferEncoding:[] Close:false Host:api.github.com Form:map[] PostForm:map[] MultipartForm:<nil> Trailer:map[] RemoteAddr: RequestURI: TLS:<nil> Cancel:<nil> Response:<nil> ctx:0xc00000c0a0} received non 2xx response status &{%!q(*http.body=&{0xc00
0384060 <nil> <nil> false false {0 0} false false false <nil>}) {'\\x00' '\\x00'} %!q(bool=false) <nil> %!q(func(error) error=0x6be580) %!q(func() error=0x6be500)} with body &{Method:POST URL:https://api.github.com/app/installations/140xx928/access_tokens Proto:HTTP/1.1 ProtoMajor:1 ProtoMinor:1 Header:map[Acce
pt:[application/vnd.github.machine-man-preview+json application/vnd.github.machine-man-preview+json] Authorization:[Bearer eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJleHAiOjE2MTAzOTUyNDEsImlhdCI6MTYxMDM5NTE4MSwiaXNzIjoiOTU4MDQifQ.UUistaOIXBImexxxxxxxxxxxj2eLTHsK24gpJ86pk053FXM3NniStaYIDmzF9CbxBZN4gb0FufnTxKO1rF3WKLiDeLD372__8RCyuxmFHTFQ-D56OpjxPgI5nl83kSvnAS5doAR1fAd-h2qh6IXhiIjmdgBKZhJRWgRu2TBZOrpVPuCxTRxEGoQUqRKRVDyfSWgHqEVCo3GWvZUG0ClWqGHr6adl2Ca0g] Content-Type:[application/json]] Body:{Reader:} GetBo
dy:0x6bcbe0 ContentLength:5 TransferEncoding:[] Close:false Host:api.github.com Form:map[] PostForm:map[] MultipartForm:<nil> Trailer:map[] RemoteAddr: RequestURI: TLS:<nil> Cancel:<nil> Response:<nil> ctx:0xc00000c0a0} and TLS &{Version:772 HandshakeComplete:true DidResume:false CipherSuite:4865 NegotiatedProt
ocol:http/1.1 NegotiatedProtocolIsMutual:true ServerName:api.github.com PeerCertificates:[0xc00000ac00 0xc00000b180] VerifiedChains:[[0xc00000b700 0xc00025a000 0xc00025a580]] SignedCertificateTimestamps:[] OCSPResponse:[] TLSUnique:[] ekm:0x62f720}"
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution or at least the cause of the problem is here:

After delimiting the problem I have arrived at the root, an issue with the configuration of the computer (securitized). On another computer with Linux and even another with Windows without these limitations, it works correctly and it can refresh the token without any problem.

So the problem was neither in the implemented code nor in the bot configuration, nor in Ngrok.